# How can I display only the thumbnail and title of a post in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, themes, thumbnails, title

How can I display only the thumbnail and title of a post in WordPress like here: http://themes.premiumpixels.com/?theme=artiste

P.S. I'm not advertising anything, I just posted a question because I have no idea how to do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

// From your loop just remove the_content() or the_excerpt() call

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
               <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
               <!-- do stuff ... -->
               if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail  assigned to it.
                  the_post_thumbnail();
               }
                post_title();// to display the post title
               <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: don't think is what he's asking.

Comment: didnt he just want to show the post thumbnail and title ...if I am not wrong the sol you provided would show the text excerpt form the post (I think which would be 40 characters by default)

Comment: i maybe wrong but according to that link there isn't just a title but some extra little info together with it

Comment: i also think he doesn't know about the_post_thumbnail().. so i'm pretty usre he doesn't know about adding that in function.php too, that's why i linked him to a tuto

Comment: I think those are just the categories ... but u are right about adding the_post_thumbnail() in functions.php...I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this for the image:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-post-thumbnails-in-wordpress/

And you need to do this for the little text:

Add this in function.php:

```
  add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

then add this below your post_thumbnail in your template as the link demonstrate you:

```
    <?php  the_exceprt(); ?>
```